# Raise an Exception on User Input

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, except

I'm trying to grasp my head around try/except. Please see code below....

```
status = raw_input('What is your status?')


#if x is anything other othan "citizen", "legal", or "illegal" raise a ValueError


try:
    status == "citizen" or status == "legal" or status == "illegal"
except:
    raise ValueError
```

So, I want to raise a ValueError if the user inputs anything other than what is specified, which doesn't happen. I know I can just use an If statement and raise a ValueError that way. But why would this not work also. Should the code not jump the except block if anything within the Try block is False?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't.  The question of **try** is not whether a condition evaluates to true; it's whether the block of statements raises an exception.  Your "status ==" expression will not raise an exception, so the "except" block won't be executed.

```
status = "other"

try:
    status == "citizen" or status == "legal" or status == "illegal"
except:
    raise ValueError

print "finished nicely"
```

Output:

```
finished nicely
```

Whereas this *does* give us an exception:

```
status = "other"
option_dict = {
    "citizen": 1,
    "legal": 2,
    "illegal": 3
}

try:
    option = option_dict[status]
except:
    raise ValueError

print "finished nicely"
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wdwickar/QA_Test/testcases/so.py", line 11, in <module>
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

Without the **try-except** block, we get

```
KeyError: 'other'
```